# What css pseudo class should I use, to capture classes with a specific naming pattern?

Tags: css

For instance, is it possible to use one selector for the following classes

`.bikes-panel, .cars-panel, .trucks-panel`
such that you have a selector that looks like

`.?????panel{ css code goes here}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*[class$="-panel"]` will do what you're looking for, however only if the .???-panel is the last class named in the class attribute.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @Dan I actually recommend @Oriol reply as theirs works as well if the class is not the last one in the `class` attribute (see their code snippet).

Comment: Thank you, I'll be looking at that as well.

Answer (score 5):

A [class](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) is delimited by [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character), which are

> U+0020 SPACE, "tab" (U+0009), "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), and "CR" (U+000D)

Then, if you want to select all elements that contain a class which ends with `-panel`, you can use the selector

```css
[class$="-panel"], [class*="-panel "], [class*="-panel\9"],
[class*="-panel\a"], [class*="-panel\c"], [class*="-panel\d"]
```

It will select all elements whose `class` attribute ends with `-panel` or contains `-panel` followed by a class delimiter.

```css
[class$="-panel"], [class*="-panel "], [class*="-panel\9"],
[class*="-panel\a"], [class*="-panel\c"], [class*="-panel\d"] {
  color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo bar-panel">foo bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel foo">bar-panel foo</div>
<div class="foo bar-panel bar">foo bar-panel bar</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo&#x9;bar-panel">foo&amp;#x9;bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel&#x9;foo">bar-panel&amp;#x9;foo</div>
<div class="foo&#x9;bar-panel&#x9;bar">foo&amp;#x9;bar-panel&amp;#x9;bar</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo&#xa;bar-panel">foo&amp;#xa;bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel&#xa;foo">bar-panel&amp;#xa;foo</div>
<div class="foo&#xa;bar-panel&#xa;bar">foo&amp;#xa;bar-panel&amp;#xa;bar</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo&#xc;bar-panel">foo&amp;#xc;bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel&#xc;foo">bar-panel&amp;#xc;foo</div>
<div class="foo&#xc;bar-panel&#xc;bar">foo&amp;#xc;bar-panel&amp;#xc;bar</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo&#xd;bar-panel">foo&amp;#xd;bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel&#xd;foo">bar-panel&amp;#xd;foo</div>
<div class="foo&#xd;bar-panel&#xd;bar">foo&amp;#xd;bar-panel&amp;#xd;bar</div>
<hr />
<div class="foo&#xf;bar-panel">foo&amp;#xf;bar-panel</div>
<div class="bar-panel&#xf;foo">bar-panel&amp;#xf;foo</div>
<div class="foo&#xf;bar-panel&#xf;bar">foo&amp;#xf;bar-panel&amp;#xf;bar</div>
```

Comment: Not understanding why this got a downvote - it looks perfectrly fine to me and is way more elaborate than my own answer. +1.

Comment: @Oriol, you put so much effort in a simple question, because you think further even than the OP, by thinking that the element could at least have 2 classes, which OP and other answeres didn't event think that. And because you didn't give a straight forward answer such as Johannes H did, you got downvoted, This is really bad. Bottom Line, Great Answer covering all the possibilities :)

Comment: Great research! Your answer actually convinced me to create a postcss-plugin supporting `:class-starts-with(prefix)` and `:class-ends-with(suffix)` to generate this code on-the-fly: https://github.com/MattDiMu/postcss-class-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For the most accurate answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37646760/3815374

Most of the current suggestions have limiations. They require the class to be the last one (which might not always be true, if you use JavaScript) or they select too much. IMO the best one is to use this:

`[class*=-panel]:not([class*=panel-])`

Comment: This will match elements with class `paneldshyfuidsfbui`. And my answer does not require it to be the last one.

Comment: Your selectors will match `.panelfoo`

Comment: Sorry, had a misspelling. It won't match .panelfoo now. But yes, this solution isn't perfect either, as it requires having some sort of css naming conventions where nobody names its classes .bikes-panelzzzz

Answer (score -2):

have you thought about making panel a class and then turning the items (bikes, cars, trucks) into id's?

for instance

```
    .panel{
code goes here
}

    #bikes{
code goes here
}

    #cars{
code goes here
}

    #trucks{
code goes here
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

if you wanted to use pseudo class, I guess you could just simply call them all

```
.panel:nth-child(specify which child){
code goes here
}
```

Comment: AN additional wrapper element to solve a problem that can easily be solved otherwise (and is a poor design choice in the first place...) is a bit of an overkill, don't you think?